# How to Get Name Property of ADODB Recordset?

Tags: ms-access, vba

How do I get the name of an ADODB recordset in VBA?
DAO has a .Name property but ADODB does not seem to have that.

At first I assumed there is no such property but now, I think there has to be.

If you set the recordset of a form programmatically, and then close and save the form WITHOUT setting the recordset property to nothing, the forms recordsource property will be filled out with the name of the recordset that you opened.

Example:

I set the recordset like this

```
Set Me.Recordset = oDal.OpenRecordset("tblOptionList")
```

If I do not do

```
Set Me.Recordset = Nothing
```

tblOptionList will be in the forms recordsource property

Here is my function that opens Recordsets

```
Public Function OpenRecordset(ByVal Tablename As String) As         ADODB.Recordset
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient

    FilePath = GetFilePath(Tablename)

    'Try to get a connection
    Connection

    If ConnOpen Then
        Set rs.ActiveConnection = pDbConn
        rs.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
        rs.LockType = adLockOptimistic
        rs.Open Tablename

        If pEnableOffline Then
            SaveOffline rs, Tablename
        End If
    Else
        'No connection, check for offline availablility

        If Dir(FilePath) <> "" And pEnableOffline Then
            rs.Open FilePath
        Else
            MsgBox "No Offline data and Server is Unavailable"
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If

    Set OpenRecordset = rs

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ADODB.Recordset.Source` property is the counterpart to the `DAO.Recordset.Name` property.

If the recordset's data source is a table or saved query, those properties will give you its name.  If the data source is a `SELECT` statement, those properties will show you the statement text.

Comment: Duh! Why did I not see that property? I thought I Searched every single property.

Comment: Well, there may be more to it than I described.  Apparently you can set the `Source` to a `Command` object.  But I don't generally use ADO, so wasn't motivated enough to investigate that one.  ;-)